# Basic UiApp failing with error "ReferenceError: "UIApp" is not defined."

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating some google app scripts for my company to use to generate random tests for employee training.  I already have the basic scripts written to grab a list of questions from a google sheet, randomize them, grab the first 10 questions, etc.  That all works fine.  I decided it might be better to re-do the whole thing using a UiApp instead of just separate scripts.  That is where the problem comes in.  I did a simple bare bones UiApp to test with, published it and tried to hit the URL and that's where I encounter this error.   I searched for this error and all I could find was some discussion about this being part of google apps premiere(which should have been folded into regular google apps around 2010).  I've been staring at this so long I've frustrated myself.  It should be something very simple and yet it's refusing to work.  I'm assuming I am doing something wrong at a basic level but I've reached the point where my brain refuses to see it.

Here is the basic script I started with:

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel');
mainPanel.add(app.createLabel('test'));
return app;
}
```

I save it, publish it and go to the URL and that's when I get the above error message.  I know it's something simple but I've reached the point of frustration and simply can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** *to reflect comments*
Another possibility for WebApps not updating is not publishing a new version and only checking the `exec` URL. For instant changes to the code, always check the `dev` URL. The `exec` will only change after saving a version in *Manage Versions* and re-publishing the app.

**First Answer:**
I think your question title says it all.

`UIApp` is not defined, but Class is `UiApp`. JS is case sensitive. I copied and pasted the code exactly as it is in your question and received no errors. I did have to add one line to make the label show up.

```
function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel');
    mainPanel.add(app.createLabel('test'));

    app.add(mainPanel); // <-- I added this line to see the label

    return app;
}
```

Comment: I checked the case first thing.  I noticed the capital "I" in the error when it first occurred and thought I had capitalized it by mistake. It's correct in my code UiApp

Comment: Are you checking the `/exec` URL or the dev URL? If you are checking the `/exec` URL, then you'll need to save a new version and re-publish the web app. The dev URL should show the changes right away.

Comment: You good sir are a genius.  I was doing the /exec URL.  I tried the dev URL and it worked like a champ.  I can't tell you how much better I feel now.  I honestly thought I was losing my mind. :-)

Comment: Updated answer to reflect true issue.